# Why the Embedded Image sent through the LinkedResource is also attached as an Attachement

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am sending the email using C#

This is a piece of the code i am using:

```
LinkedResource Lnkr = new LinkedResource(LogoPath);
Lnkr.ContentType.Name = "Logo.jpg";

Lnkr.ContentId = "Image1";
AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<br/><img src='cid:Image1'/>", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
av1.LinkedResources.Add(Lnkr);
Emailmsg.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
```

**Please Don't recommend to use the image path as directly pick from some server like "http://ww.a.jpg"**

The problem is the image is displayed but is also added as an attachment.
I dont the image to be added as an attachement.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has to be stored somewhere, so it's attached to your email. I you use absolute path in your img src then the image isn't attached.

You can embed the image as a 64based string but I don't think that is supported by a lot of email clients.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: Your answer seems to be helpful. Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is this is windows application and we cannot have some server to store the image and my client will not accept the image as an attachement

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the image mime type in the LinkedResource constructor:
    LinkedResource Lnkr = new LinkedResource(LogoPath, "image/jpeg");

It worked for me when using Outlook, but not Gmail Webmail